# BizTalk mapper does not display element of external Data Structure Type residing in other assembly

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

I am having trouble mapping to a target element, which is an imported element in the destination schema, specified via the Data Structure Type setting. The actual import is from another assembly (NuGet - no source xsd).

The schema editor displays the actual entity schema correctly and I am able to navigate the schema tree in editor:

[image]

Then when I try to use that schema in a map, the imported node is displayed only with its parent node, it is not possible to expand its child nodes.

[image]

Anyone? 2020 issue?

Comment: Opening the schema in xml editor, there is a warning in import declaration, telling that the xsd file is not found in the schemaLocation given. However, the schema editor do find the schema from the assembly anyway. Unfortunately, the map tool requires xsd...to even display the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described, this seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- Install the NuGet reference in your map project as you did in your schema project for the imported element.
- Try using another value for 'Origin' since you now have a nested Origin - Origin structure that might be too complicated.
- Try setting the reference path as an absolute or relative, see if it makes a difference.
- Try to use the complex or simple type on the **Data Structure Type** dropdown if that's available on the imported schema.